# redirect to another action with hidden or post parameter in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, response.redirect, cakephp-3.2

I'm working cakephp 3.2

I have to redirect from one action to another along with some data with it. The data to be transmitted is large and in a variable and also sensitive.

Passing the data in parameter can be achieved by

```
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'myAction', $param]);
```

But this gives url as

```
/my-controller/my-action/param
```

I do not want to show `param` in the url.

Is there some way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some way to do this ?

You could simply use the session to stash the data.

E.g. In the function with post data:

```
$this->request->session()->write(
    'my-stuff', 
    $this->request->data
);
$this->redirect('/somewhere/else');
```

In the function that needs that data, read it out of the session:

```
$myStuff = $this->request->session()->read('my-stuff');
if (!$myStuff) {
    return $this->redirect('/start/point');
}
...
```